Having problem with arrayformula and sequence functions
I have a sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15lwtkTifZDrLICMFp_Dr17gkq8hfSCfG6dydVhK_T4I/edit?usp=sharing
in which (column B) I am trying to combine arrayformula() with sequence(). It is clear to me that it cannot work, but I am not able to figure out how to do a workaround. Column C shows the result I want.
In real life, it is not about putting number under each other, the formula is more complicated but the idea is the same.
I will be helpful for any insight.
I tried playing with makearray() and other ways.


Here's one general approach you may test out:
=reduce(tocol(,1),A2:A4,lambda(a,c,vstack(a,{sequence(c),let(Σ,offset(c,,1),wrapcols(Σ,c,Σ))})))



Unbelievable, Thanks.
